# Add a project on local solution but not in source control (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

EDIT:

I have an existig solution in visual studio (which is on TFS source control). In this solution, I have several projects too (under source control).

Now, I would like to add a project (for test purpose) to my solution, but I would like this project only on my local computer and not commit it on the source control, because all other team members doesn't need it!

I can obviously, remove the project of source control, but while it is in the solution, all others team members will be able to see the project even if they'll not be able to load it !

Anyway to avoid .sln to add the local project ? Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ofcourse. Easiest way would be to create your own local solution file with the test project and the other projects that you need.

Comment: it's not a great solution! I would like to create the projet in the SAME solution.

Comment: You can add the project to the same solution, it will be local to your machine as long you as you choose not to check-in the changes to TFS. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add the test project to the solution without adding it to the source control. The simple reason is that the project has to be declared in the SLN file which is on source control.

So you'll have to create another solution and add existing projects and the new one.